# getting list of installed programs and installing them again on another drive

Tags: installation, 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I will be switching hard drives and upgrading to an ssd drive. 
The questions I have are:

1) How can I get a list of programs currently installed on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine.
2) how can install those programs again on the new 13.10 drive without reinstalling each program one by one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get a list of all installed packages and store that list into a file in your user directory:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/packages.list
```

Then to use that to install the packages on another PC:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/packages.list; sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use Aptik to do this task using a GUI instead a CLI (personally I prefer the CLI method described above, but here you have another possible solution). Aptik allows you to Backup & Restore your favourite App's, PPA's and many more!

You can get Aptik from official PPA using this simple line:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

[Here](https://launchpad.net/apt-toolkit) you have more info about Aptik:

I used several times in university computers (I'm the SysAdmin) after a fresh Ubuntu installation and this tool help me to save a lot of time.

Also I recommend you Timeshift to make an OS image backup from same author (Clonezilla randomly failed when restoring an HDD image disk into a SSD and really), but also I recommend you Ubuntu AfterInstall wich you can to install a lot of useful software (restricted extras, VLC, etc...) using only a few mouse clicks.